# How to do an addition on a list with a condition?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, higher-order-functions, fold

I have a university course about functional programming, where I use SML. As a preparation for the exam, I am working on some of the older exam sets without solutions.

One of the only questions I really have problems with is the following question using `foldl`:

> Consider the program skeleton: fun
> addGt k xs = List.foldl (...) ... xs;
> Fill in the two missing pieces
> (represented by the dots ...), so that
> addGt k xs is the sum of those
> elements in xs, which are greater than
> k. For example, addGt 4 [1, 5, 2, 7,
> 4, 8] = 5 + 7 + 8 = 20

I am sure this is really easy, but I have a very hard time understanding the foldl and foldr functions.

What I have now is the following (which seems to be very wrong if you ask my compiler!):

```
fun addGt(k,xs) = List.foldl ( fn x => if x > k then op+ else 0) 0 xs;
```

I would really appreciate some help with this question, and maybe a very short comment which would cast some light on the `foldl` and `foldr` functions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A solution that I just though of is the following:

```
fun addGt(k, xs) = List.foldl (fn (x, y) => if x >= 5  then x + y else y) 0 xs;
```

But let me explain. First of all check the type of the `List.foldl` function, it's:

```
('a * 'b -> 'b) -> 'b -> 'a list -> 'b
```

So `List.foldl` is a [curried](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/MoggiE/LP/SML/NOTES/node33.html) function that takes as first parameter another function of type `('a * 'b -> 'b)`. You used `(fn x => if x > k then op+ else 0)` which has type `int -> int`. You should instead provide `List.foldl` with a function that takes a tuple of type `int * int` and returns an `int`, so something like this: `(fn (x, y) => do stuff)`. That's why your code didn't compile, you passed a wrong type of function in `foldl`.

Now you can think of `foldl` this way:

`foldl f b [x_1, x_2, ..., x_(n - 1), x_n] = f(x_n, f(x_(n - 1), ..., f(x2, f(x1, b)) ...))` where `f` is a function of type `('a * 'b -> 'b)`, `b` is something of type `'b` and the list `[x_1, x_2, ..., x_(n - 1), x_n]` is of type `'a list`.

And similar for `foldr` you can think it in this way:

`foldr f b [x_1, x_2, ..., x_(n - 1), x_n] = f(x_1, f(x_2, ..., f(x_(n - 1), f(x_ n, b))`

Comment: I assume you meant `if x >= k`?

Answer (score 2):

If you call `foldl f s ls` on a list, `ls = [x1, x2, ..., xn]`, then you get the result:

```
f(xn, ... f(x2, f(x1, s)))
```

That is, it starts by finding

```
a1 = f(x1, s)
```

Then

```
a2 = f(x2, a1)
```

and so on, until it's through the list.

When it's done, it returns `an`.

You can think of the `a`-values as being a sort of *accumulator*, that is, `ai` is the result as it would be if the list was only `[x1, x2, ..., xi]` (or rather, the first i elements of the list).

Your function will usually have the form:

```
fn (x, a) => ...
```

What you then need to do is think: Okay, if I have the next element in the list, `x(i+1)`, and the value `ai`, which is the result for the list `[x1, x2, ..., xi]`, what do I need to do to find the value `a(i+1)`, which is the result for the list `[x1, x2, ..., xi, x(i+1)]`.

`s` can be thought of as the value given to the empty list.

`foldr` works the same way, only you start from the back of the list instead of from the front.